# Custom directive v-focus is not working on vuetify component

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use a vuejs custom directive called focus on a component from vuetify which is `v-field-text`.

```
directives: {
    focus: {
      // directive definition
      inserted: function(el) {
        el.focus();
      }
    }
  }
```

I have a todo list, and my todos are printed with `v-for`, I also have an option to edit todos, whenever i click on edit button todo dispears and todo edit input apears. 
I am using this focus directive to auto focusing the input. 
 
However when i use this like this is not working:

```
<v-field-text v-focus></v-field-text>
```

But it works like this:

```
<input v-focus />
```

When i `console.log` the `el` from the directive, i see that its referring to a `div` element created by vuetify.
How to fix this issue?

Comment: Maybe bcs `<v-field-text v-focus></v-text-field>` has a typo? it should be `<v-text-field....>`

Comment: No, sorry i did a typo in writing the question.

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're seeing a `div` when using `v-focus` on those elements is because they are being wrapped in a div.  To get around this with third party components you don't control the code to, you may use something like the following function:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.directive('focus', {
  inserted: function(el) {
    // Recursion based function for finding an input
    // nested within other elements.
    let findInput = (el, max_depth = 5) => {
      // We found the input, so we return it, which causes
      // the entire function stack to pop
      if (el.nodeName === 'INPUT') {
        return el
      }

      // Prevent infinite recursion by providing a maximum
      // depth, and returning when we've reached that depth
      if (max_depth === 0) {
        return null
      }

      // Our current element is not an input, so we need to loop
      // over its children and call findInput recursively
      for (let child of el.children) {

        let input = findInput(child, max_depth - 1)

        // We've found our input, return it to unwind the stack
        // otherwise, continue through the loop
        if (input) {
          return input
        }
      }

      // Fallback in case for when el has no children, or we reached the end of the loop with no input
      return null
    }

    // Start searching for the input.  We can optionally
    // pass a higher max_depth.  Use with caution.
    let input = findInput(el, 20)

    if (input) {
      input.focus()
    }
  }
})
```

This is using recursion to step through each elements children, searching for an element with `nodeName === 'INPUT'`.

As an example, the following complex structure would be parsed and the first input found would be focused:

```
<div v-focus>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                Hello
              </div>
              <p>
                world
              </p>
              <span>!</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <input type="text" value="I will be focused">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this solution. It's working for me:

```
 directives: {
        focus: {
          // directive definition
      inserted: function (el) {
          let childData = el.querySelectorAll("input")[0]; 
          childData.focus()
        }
          }
        }
```